# React JS Swiper Loop unable to correctly loop through objects

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

My Swiper will not work inside of React and I have tried fixing it several times. But I haven't been able to solve it. Swiper is fully up to date.

```
import React from "react";
import "./testimonial.css";
import { Data } from "./Data";

import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

import {Pagination} from "swiper/modules"


const Testimonials = () => {
    return (
        <section className="testimonial container section">
            <h2 className="section_title">My Clients Say</h2>
            <span className="section_subtitle">Testimonial</span>

            <Swiper className="testimonial_container"
            loop={true}
            grabCursor={true}
            spaceBetween={24}
            pagination={{
              clickable: true,
            }}
            breakpoints={{
              576: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
              },
              768: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 48,
              },
            }}
            modules={[Pagination]}>
                {Data.map(({id,image,title,description})=>{
                    return(
                        <SwiperSlide className="testimonial_card" key={id}>
                            <img src={image} alt="" className="testiomonial_img"/>

                            <h3 className="testimonial_name">{title}</h3>
                            <p className="testimonial_description">{description}</p>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                })}
            </Swiper>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Testimonials;
```

I have tried different forms of syntax, but to no avail. I want to be able to infinitely scroll through my objects, but it keeps getting stuck on the second slide.